# Динамический селект сортировки продуктов по годам

Tags: php, select, mysql

Всех с праздником!
Давно хочу сделать динамический селект сортировки продуктов по годам и вывода в 5 столбцов и 5 строк на странице - не знаю как сделать. Для меня задача сложная. Прошу помочь как правильно его сделать? Может кто-то уже писал?

В итоге хочу получить вывод продуктов по 5 столбцам и 5 строкам на лист. Сортировка должна пройти по Годам (product_categ_id таблица t_product_categs; сами продукты в таблице t_product столбик categ_id)

Вывод очевидно должен быть такой:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_product WHERE parent_id = '".$_GET['id']."' ORDER BY name ASC");

$arr = array();

while($rows = mysql_fetch_row($res)){

    $arr[] = $rows[0];

}

Таблица t_product_categs

 product_categ_id   parent_id   title
            19       NULL       2011
            20       NULL       2012

Таблица  t_product

product_id   categ_id   brand_id   logo_id

    235        20         18    code-130r.jpg
    236        19         20    exp-9f.jpg
    237        20         21    emerg-e.jpg
```

Comment: Поясните конкретно, что Вы хотите получить в итоге: какие столбцы из каких таблиц и по какому столбцу отсортированные?

Comment: Пояснил все в вопросе...

Comment: Используемые Вами методы слегка устарели. Думаю будет полезней, если Вы сразу пимите за правило использовать PDO http://www.php.su/functions/?pdo-query

Comment: Спасибо попробую...

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

```
SELECT p.*, pc.title
  FROM t_product p
 INNER JOIN t_product_categs pc ON p.categ_id = pc.product_categ_id
 WHERE pc.parent_id = :parent_id
 ORDER BY pc.title
 LIMIT 5
```

Но все же было бы неплохо увидеть, хотя бы, какие поля вам нужно выбрать и предполагаемый результирующий набор данных.

Comment: Спасибо попробую сделать, о результате напишу..